# Exec-queries when i rewrite code from sql to ruby

Tags: mysql, ruby

```
SELECT users.* 
FROM users 
WHERE (users.id NOT IN  (
   SELECT user_id
     FROM replacers 
)
OR users.id IN (
SELECT  users.id
from users
LEFT JOIN replacers ON users.id = replacers.user_id 
WHERE (replacers.replacer_id IS NULL AND replacers.end_date  < NOW())
)) AND users.id IN (SELECT user_id FROM members WHERE project_id=1387) - working code sql
```

Can we rewrite it on ruby? U can see how i tried but have error exec-queries

```
users = User.joins("
    LEFT JOIN #{Replacer.table_name} 
    WHERE (#{User.table_name}.id 
    NOT IN (SELECT user_id FROM #{Replacer.table_name}))
    OR #{User.table_name}.id IN (SELECT id from #{User.table_name} 
    WHERE (#{Replacer.table_name}.replacer_id IS NULL AND #{Replacer.table_name}.end_date < NOW()
    )) AND #{User.table_name}.id IN (SELECT user_id FROM #{Member.table_name} 
    WHERE #{Member.table_name}.project_id", {project_id:context[:issue].project_id})
    .all.map { |u| [u.name(format), u.id] } - wrong code doesnt work on ruby
```

Can you help me where is my error in my ruby code?

Comment: Rewrite your code, remove WHERE [NOT] IN and use JOIN instead.

Comment: What do you want to do with the raw sql?

Comment: Can you use ActiveRecord?